Javascript jQuery activate a class method after click event in class object
syntax for starting the class method
Creation of myClass is oke but when event the method of the class doesn't work
class myClass {
  constructor(toElement, options) {
    var self = this;
    this.toElement = toElement;
    this.options = options;
    this.generateElement();
    this.shuffle; // works fine
  }
  generateElement() {
    let myElement;

    myElement = document.createElement('input');
    myElement.type = 'text';
    myElement.placeholder = 'Search';
    myElement.id = 'IDtext';
    myElement.addEventListener("keyup", this.eventInputKeyUp);
    myElement.value = '';
    document.getElementById(this.toElement).appendChild(myElement);

    myElement = document.createElement('input');
    myElement.type = 'button';
    myElement.id = 'IDbutton';
    myElement.value = '▽';
    myElement.addEventListener("click", this.eventInputClick);
    document.getElementById(this.toElement).appendChild(myElement);

  }
  eventInputKeyUp() {
    console.log(this.id)
    this.shuffle();                     // ERROR is not a function

  }
  eventInputClick() {
    console.log(this.id)
    self.shuffle();                    // ERROR in not a function

  }

  shuffle() {
    console.log('shuffle', this.options);
  }
}

let x = new myClass('test', 'Hello');


NOT WORKING JSFIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/pollentier_steven/cymje9L8/29/

When you pass a method you lose this when the event calls the handler.
You should either bind this:
myElement.addEventListener("keyup", this.eventInputKeyUp.bind(this));

or better use an arrow function:
myElement.addEventListener("keyup", () => this.eventInputKeyUp());


Alternatively delegate https://jsfiddle.net/d9aqszr0/
